# python 3 url concatenate from file and list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, concatenation

I have a file that has multiple urls and list with url paths. I am trying to concatenate or join them together with the url paths in the list. I am having a lot of trouble trying to get this to work.

file has urls like this

```
foobar.com
foobar.com.tk
foobar.org
```

```
list1 = ['/foobar.php','/foobar.html','/foobar.php']

with open('file1.txt') as f:
    Nlist = [line.strip() for line in f]
```

I don't know if it matters or not but the file with urls doesn't have the http:// header and when I try to join the urls from the list with the  paths I keep getting an error or the code is all bunched up...How do I join the urls from the file with the paths from the list?

Comment: Can you share the output you expect to get for this sample data? It would help make the question clearer

Comment: Please provide more details for the error and any actual/expected output. You can concatenate lists using ``list_a + list_b``, regardless of where their data comes from.

Comment: oh yea I'm sorry I meant to do that, but forgot the output should look something like this 
```
http://foobar.com/foobar.php
http://foobar.org/foobar.html
http://foobar.com.tk/foobar.php
or
foobar.com/foobar.php
foobar.org/foobar.html
foobar.com.tk/foobar.php
```

Comment: so will i have to put the file into a list first? i am trying to iterate through them so I can make a post request with each individual url...if i do list_a + list_b it just adds the list together I need to be able to join the urls in the file with the paths in the list so they form a url http://foobar.com/foobar.php like that....

Comment: `lines = list(open(filename, 'r'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get every url combination with `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product
from pprint import pprint

list1 = ["/foobar.php", "/foobar.html", "/foobar.php"]

with open("file1.txt") as f:
    pprint(
        set(
            "https://%s%s" % (root, path)
            for root, path in product(map(str.strip, f), list1)
        )
    )
```

Urls:

```
{'https://foobar.com.tk/foobar.html',
 'https://foobar.com.tk/foobar.php',
 'https://foobar.com/foobar.html',
 'https://foobar.com/foobar.php',
 'https://foobar.org/foobar.html',
 'https://foobar.org/foobar.php'}
```

**Note:** You can use `set()` here to remove duplicate urls from the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = ['/foobar.php','/foobar.html','/foobar.php']

with open('file1.txt') as f:
    Nlist = [line.strip() for line in f]

for i in range(len(Nlist)):
    pth = 'https://' + Nlist[i] + list1[i]
    print(pth)
```

`os.path.join()` doesn't seem to like all of the dot whatevers, so it seems that you have to resort to your own concatenation.